# Acquire IPropertySetStorage for File in Recycle Bin

Tags: c++, properties, com, windows-shell

I'm attempting to enumerate file properties from files (Title, Author, etc) and have found that enumerating files in the Recycle Bin in particular are being problematic. However, having identified what I believe to be the problem, I am sure that other folders might exhibit the same issues.

I have found that the [ITEMIDLIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773321%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)s created via methods such as [ILCreateFromPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378420%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [ParseDisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are affected(see below) by the desktop.ini's located in certain special folders, which will result in an `ITEMIDLIST` that fails when used in the [BindToObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or [SHBindToObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762113%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) that I have used to acquire the [IPropertySetStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379840%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interface for a file, which I am using to enumerate file properties.

To describe what I mean by "affected by desktop.ini's", what I have found is that it returns a path that is altered in name by the desktop.ini, such as by translating the "LocalizedResourceName" in the desktop.ini and the path returned in the `ITEMIDLIST` is no longer consistent with the *actual* path on disk. This causes the Bind methods to fail with HRESULT 0x80070002.

Based on the debugging and research I have done, I presume there are two possible solutions to my problem. However, I do not currently know how to do either, or in fact if either is possible. This brings me to this set of questions:

1) Is it possible to obtain an `ITEMIDLIST` through some method which is NOT affected by the desktop.ini's that may be located in a folder?

2) Is there some way to obtain a file's `IPropertySetStorage` interface *without* the use of an `ITEMIDLIST`?

Alternatively, if anyone has a better method for acquiring this information about files in general, I'd appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The shell property page isn't available for files in recycle bin in Windows Explorer as well, so I guess the answer is no.

Comment: I am able to perfectly enumerate the data that I seek when I remove the desktop.ini files, and I can visibly see the change in the ITEMIDLIST to depict the actual file path. Keep in mind that the physical file itself is not altered when it is placed in the Recycle Bin. The data is still there, it is merely Explorer itself that chooses to display things differently (based on desktop.ini-foo).

Comment: Yes, but you are asking IPropertySetStorage from a special Explorer folder view that has the desktop.ini.